# using excel VBA to grab data from a web page that runs scrpits to show the table data

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Day two of researching this. I'm just not getting it. The web page is public:
https://register.fca.org.uk/ShPo_FirmDetailsPage?id=001b000000MfF1EAAV
Manually I pgdn x 2 to get to the button [+] Individuals, click it then pgdn x 1 to get to the "results per page" drop down and change it to 500. then copy and paste the results into excel

this is the code that I found on this site "Selecting a dropdown list when inserting data from web (VBA)" answered by QHarr which I tried to adapt and failed miserably. I put "HELP" where I think I should be making the changes but I'm just guessing

```
Public Sub MakeSelectiongGetData()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Const URL = "https://register.fca.org.uk/ShPo_FirmDetailsPage?id=001b000000Mfe5TAAR#ShPo_FirmDetailsPage"
'Const optionText As String = "RDVT11"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate URL

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim a As Object
    Set a = .document.getElementById("HELP")

    Dim currentOption As Object
    For Each currentOption In a.getElementsByTagName("HELP")
        If InStr(currentOption.innerText, optionText) > 0 Then
            currentOption.Selected = "HELP"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentOption
    .document.getElementById("HELP").Click
    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim nTable As HTMLTable

    Do: On Error Resume Next: Set nTable = .document.getElementById("HELP"): On Error GoTo 0: DoEvents: Loop While nTable Is Nothing

    Dim nRow As Object, nCell As Object, r As Long, c As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim nBody As Object
        Set nBody = nTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
        .Cells(1, 1) = nBody(0).innerText
        For r = 2 To nBody.Length - 1
            Set nRow = nBody(r)
            For Each nCell In nRow.Cells
                c = c + 1: .Cells(r + 1, c) = nCell.innerText
            Next nCell
            c = 0
      Next r
End With
.Quit
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So I have included your changes and am here.

```
Public Sub MakeSelections()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate2 "https://register.fca.org.uk/ShPo_FirmDetailsPage?id=001b000000MfF1EAAV"

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    .document.querySelector("[href*=FirmIndiv]").Click '<==click the + for indiv
    .document.querySelector("#IndividualSearchResults_length[value='500']").Selected = True
End With

Dim nTable As HTMLTable

Do: On Error Resume Next: Set nTable =IE.document.getElementById("IndividualSearchResults"): On Error GoTo 0: DoEvents: Loop While nTable Is Nothing

Dim nRow As Object, nCell As Object, r As Long, c As Long

With ActiveSheet
    Dim nBody As Object
    Set nBody = nTable.getElementsByTagName("Name")(0) _
                      .getElementsByTagName("ShG1_IRN_c") _
                      .getElementsByTagName("ShGl_IndividualStatus__c") _
                      .getElementsByTagName("ShPo_Registerstatus__c") _
                      .getElementsByTagName("Id") _
                      .getElementsByTagName("RecordTypeId") _
                      .getElementsByTagName("CurrencyIsoCode") _
    .Cells(1, 1) = nBody(0).innerText
    For r = 2 To nBody.Length - 1
        Set nRow = nBody(r)
        For Each nCell In nRow.Cells
            c = c + 1: .Cells(r + 1, c) = nCell.innerText
        Next nCell
        c = 0
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selectors to target the + for individuals and also to make the option selection for 500

```
 Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub MakeSelections()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://register.fca.org.uk/ShPo_FirmDetailsPage?id=001b000000MfF1EAAV"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("[href*=FirmIndiv]").Click '<==click the + for indiv
        .document.querySelector("#IndividualSearchResults_length [value='500']").Selected = True

        Dim event_onchange As Object
        Set event_onchange = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        event_onchange.initEvent "change", True, False

        .document.querySelector("[name=IndividualSearchResults_length]").dispatchEvent event_onchange

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
        Dim clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet

        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        clipboard.SetText .document.querySelector("#IndividualSearchResults").outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

This selector, `[href*=FirmIndiv]`, is an attribute = value selector with contains (*) modifier. It looks for the matches for `href` attributes that contain the substring `FirmIndiv` in the `href` value. querySelector all method of `HTMLDocument` *(ie.Document) will return the first match found.

You can see the match here:

[image]

The selector for the `option` tag element (the parent `select` tag for result counts contains child `option` tag elements):

```
#IndividualSearchResults_length [value='500']
```

It uses an [id (#) selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) to target the div parent, of the parent `select` element, by its id value `IndividualSearchResults_length`, then uses a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) (" ") followed by attribute = value selector to specify the `option` element with `value` = `500`.

You can see that here:

[image]

---

**Selenium basic version:**

```
Option Explicit 
Public Sub MakeChanges()
'VBE > Tools > References > Selenium Type Library
'Download: https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const url = "https://register.fca.org.uk/ShPo_FirmDetailsPage?id=001b000000MfF1EAAV"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get url
        .FindElementByCss("[href*=FirmIndiv]").Click
         .FindElementByCss("[name=IndividualSearchResults_length]").WaitDisplayed True, 10000
         .FindElementByCss("[name=IndividualSearchResults_length]").AsSelect.SelectByValue "500"
        Stop                                     '<==delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Any questions let me know

Comment: Hi, two question. Setting the value to 500 changes the count on the page but does not activate refresh the table. So then I found the table that was generated under aaData and tried to pull the data using getElementsByTagName but to no avail

Comment: So it now looks like this

Comment: Let me know if that is as expected.

Comment: Worked a treat, sadly couldn't use selenium version due to software usage restriction. But have everything I needed Thank you

Comment: Please can you explain this line
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

Comment: It creates a late bound version of clipboard object so no reference to MS Forms needed./

Comment: Can you think of any reason why that part of the code may throw out a command to load the file manager. The odd think about it is the sudden appearance of two to several file managers is not consistent. So my question is solely in respect to the "Set clipboard..." line.

Comment: You could try vbe > tools > references > then add reference to  Microsoft-Forms 2.0 Object Library  and change lines to Dim clipboard As DataObject : 
Set clipboard = New DataObject. see if persists.